# How do I align images in center and overlay text on hover?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a horizontally scrolling image gallery and I am having trouble centering it in the middle of the window. I tried to add display of flex to the body and do it that way, it didn't work for me.

I'm new at flexbox so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, I'm just looking for an overall constructive criticism and guidance.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 2em;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

img {
  min-height: 400px;
  max-height: 420px;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1163637/480x480">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1163637/480x480">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1163637/480x480">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1163637/480x480">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1163637/480x480">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1163637/480x480">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1163637/480x480">
</div>
```

Here's the example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxgpRG).

Comment: better keep your question focus on own issue not a lot of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to center a div on the screen, you can change the `top` property as shown below:

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}
```

And to hide horizontal scrolling you can do this:

```
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

To overlay text on an image when you hover:

```
  <div class="img_container_1">
   <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1163637/480x480">
   <div class="overlay">
     <div class="text">Hello World</div>
   </div>
 </div>

  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.image_container_1{
   position: relative;
}

.img_container_1:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

img {
  min-height: 400px;
  max-height: 420px;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 2em;
}

.text {
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   text-align: center;
}
```

You can find the full demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJRVwb?editors=1100

Comment: Can anyone give me some insight on how add a border along the whole horizonal image gallery? I tried adding to to the wrapper and also to the images . When I added it to the images it went up along the images right side, I only set the shadows x offset.  And when adding to the wrapper it didn't stretch along the length of the gallery

Comment: You should make that a separate question.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJRVwb?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

To vertically center everything in your wrapper with flexbox, you need to add `align-items: center;` to `.wrapper`.

The wrapper is also matching the height of its contents in your example, so you won't see any difference unless you give `.wrapper` a height.

You set `body` to `height: 100%;`, which is what makes your example scroll vertically at the moment. Removing that removes the scrollbar as long as your view is big enough to hold all of its content vertically.

Adjusted CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 2em;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px; /* Example height */
  flex-direction: row; /* It's this by default, so you could remove this if you want */
}
img {
  min-height: 400px;
  max-height: 420px;
  padding-right: 2em;
}
```

I made an adjusted example on CodePen that works for reference: https://codepen.io/happikitsune/pen/rZMOWO